# Android Build failing because of JCenter

Tags: android, gradle, android-camerax, jcenter

I am trying to build Android project through jenkins but it's failing. Same build was working few days back and I did not make any changes in libraries. Here is console logs for same :

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:minifySitWithR8'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:sitCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve androidx.camera:camera-core:[1.1.0].
 Required by:
     project :app > androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0
     project :app > androidx.camera:camera-view:1.1.0
  > Failed to list versions for androidx.camera:camera-core.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/camera/camera-core/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/camera/camera-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/camera/camera-core/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I check visiting https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/camera/camera-core/maven-metadata.xml in browser but I am getting following response :

```
{
"errors" : [ {
"status" : 404,
"message" : "Maven metadata not found for 'androidx/camera/camera-core/maven-metadata.xml'."
} ]
}
```

Here is my project level gradle file :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.3'  // Performance Monitoring plugin

}
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

App level gradle file :

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 29
   buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.a.b.c"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 385
    versionName "0.55.2"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

gradle.properties  :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-bin.zip
```

I can not move to to higher gradle version which will force to upgrade my all libraries and I can not set targeted version more than 29(it need big changes to move to 31)

Need suggestions here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `jcenter()` from both `repositories` closures. `androidx.camera:camera-core` is [available from `google()`](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.camera:camera-core), which you already have.